# cibuildwheel and CUDA

Tags: docker, cuda

I'm trying to compile a binary (C++) Python package that needs CUDA. Everything works except for finding the CUDA toolkit (CMake can't find nvcc).

I have narrowed it down to the Docker container missing the CUDA toolkit. However, I have no idea how to inject this into the container.

Is there a way to run commands from within the container that gets spun up so that I can install CUDA?

Comment: Nvidia provide pre-built docker containers. Use one of those. The likelihood your own built container will work with the GPU is extremely slim, even after you solve your build issue

Comment: @talonmies it's unclear if this will work here as cibuildwheel spins up its own containers. I think there's a way to change the container but that may have implications downstream for who can run my Python package. Also, the goal is not to run the GPU code but just to compile it. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that may end up here in the future, the way to deal with this is to use the environment variable `CIBW_BEFORE_ALL`. The contents of this variable will be executed in the shell on the Docker container before proceeding with the build. I did a `yum install cuda-toolkit` from there.

My GitHub action looks like this:

```
- name: Build CUDA Linux Wheels
  run: python -m cibuildwheel --output-dir wheelhouse/cuda
  if: runner.os == 'Linux'
  env:
    CIBW_BUILD_VERBOSITY: 1
    CIBW_ARCHS_LINUX: "x86_64"
    CIBW_SKIP: "*musl*"
    CIBW_BEFORE_ALL: >
      yum-config-manager --add-repo https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel7/x86_64/cuda-rhel7.repo &&
      yum clean all &&
      yum -y install cuda-toolkit &&
      ls -al /usr/local &&
      export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin &&
      nvcc --version &&
      export BUILD_WITH_CUDA=1
```